# Mac can't connect to any WiFi networks

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

This morning I woke up and my MacBook Pro (macOs Catalina 10.15.7) WiFi stopped working. WiFi networks are working fine since with other devices I don't have any issue to connect. It's quite strange behaviour.

It shows the networks but if I try to connect it says "connection failed". After that it can't find any network at all, always "looking for networks" unless I switch off then on WiFi on my Mac and then I see the networks again but can't join then and I double check passwords.

I tried to reboot my Mac.
I tried updating my OS but it needs connection to do that.
I tried to renew DHCP with no luck.
I tried to reset DNS with no luck.

Do you have any insight reading that?

Thank you.

Comment: Try [Wi-fi Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mchlf4de377f/mac)?

Comment: I don't really know how to read diagnostics files...

Comment: You don‘t have to, just run it to have it diagnose common issues.

Comment: In System Preferences > Network > WiFi > Advanced ... button, select the Network Name of the network which is not connecting and click the minus button to delete. Click OK, then recreate the network connection. Also, if you have many WiFi Network Names in the list, delete the ones you never, or rarely, use.